# locks and nested synchronized methods

Tags: java, methods, nested, synchronized, locks

Say we have something like this,

```
class Class{    
//...
synchronized void m1(Class obj){ obj.m2(); }
synchronized void m2(){ /*...*/ }
}
```

My question - when is lock of an object obj released? When it returns from method m2, or method m1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to translate the `synchronized` methods in synchronized blocks:

```
m1(C obj) {
    synchronized(this) {
        obj.m2();
    }
}

m2() {
    synchronized(this) {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

So your `obj` Object is only locked during the `m2()` call. This is because that's the only time when `this` translates to `obj`.

The `m1()` call only locks the current object, which by the way could also be the same `obj`; if this is the case (`this == obj` in the first call), then `obj` is locked until both `m1()` and `m2()` complete.

Comment: I asked because I think I saw somewhere that the lock shouldn't be   released when we return from the inner method. But,now I suppose they thought about the same "this" object,since I believe you :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [JLS Section 17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html)

> A thread t may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation.

However, your question is complicated by the fact that `m1()` and `m2()` may lock *different* objects.  `m1()` locks whatever object you invoked it on, which you haven't shown.  So the sequence of events is:

1. You invoke `x.m1(y)` where `x` and `y` are potentially different instances of `Class`.
2. Before entering `m1`, the JVM locks the monitor for `x`.
3. `m1` invokes `m2`
4. Before entering `m2` the JVM locks the monitor for `y`.
5. When `m2` exits, the monitor for `y` is released
6. When `m1` exits, the monitor for `x` is released

If `x` and `y` are the same object, then the lock is released when `m1` exits.